# Expand the function as a Fourier series by the method of exponentials

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

$f(x) = 0, -\pi < x< \pi/2$

$f(x) = 1, \pi/2 < x < \pi$

The answer is given as:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{\pi} \left ( \frac{cosx}{1} - \frac{cos3x}{3} + \frac{cos5x}{5}... \right )+\frac{1}{\pi} \left (\frac{sinx}{1} - \frac{2sin2x}{2} + \frac{sin3x}{3} -\frac{2sin6x}{6} \right )$$

**My attempt:**

$$c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi/2} 0dx + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} e^{-inx}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \left [\frac{e^{-in\pi}}{-in} - \frac{e^{-in\pi/2}}{-in} \right ]$$

This evaluates to each of the following, depending on the noted value of $n$:

$=\frac{-1}{2\pi in} (-1+i)$ , $n=1,5,9,13,...$

$=\frac{-1}{\pi in}$, $n=2,6,10,14,...$

$\frac{-1}{2\pi in}(-1-i)$, $n=3,7,11,15,..$

$=0$, $n=4,8,12,16,...$

$c_0=\frac{1}{4}$, of course.

Putting it all together:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1-i}{2\pi i}(\frac{e^{ix}}{1}-\frac{e^-ix}{1}+\frac{e^{5ix}}{5}-\frac{e^{-5ix}}{5}+\ldots)-\frac{1}{\pi i} (\frac{e^{2ix}}{2}-\frac{e^{-2ix}}{2} +\frac{e^{6ix}}{6}-\frac{e^{-6ix}}{6}+\ldots)+$$
$$ \frac{1+i}{2\pi i} (\frac{e^{3ix}}{3}-\frac{e^{-3ix}}{3}+\frac{e^{7ix}}{7}-\frac{e^{-7ix}}{7}+\ldots)$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1-i}{\pi} (\frac{\sin x}{1}+\frac{\sin 5x}{5}+\frac{\sin 9x}{9}+\ldots )-\frac{2}{\pi}(\frac{\sin 2x}{2}+\frac{\sin 6x}{6}+\ldots)$$ $$+\frac{1+i}{\pi}(\frac{\sin 3x}{3}+\frac{\sin7x}{7}+\ldots)$$

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is not writing $\displaystyle f(x) = 1/4 + \sum_{n= -\infty, n \ne 0}^\infty e^{in x} \frac{1}{2\pi} \left (\frac{e^{-in\pi}}{-in} - \frac{e^{-in\pi/2}}{-in}\right)$. Please stop writing series by giving only the first few terms

Comment: So we just ignore the $(-i)^n$ term?

Comment: I'm assuming that's what you mean by "taking the real part", no?

Comment: Now  $e^{-in \pi} = (-1)^n$ and $e^{-in\pi  / 2} = (-i)^n$, and since $f(x)$ is real, taking the real part of $1/4+\sum_{n \ne 0} ((-1)^n +(-i)^n)\frac{1}{-i \pi n}e^{i  n x} $ you'll get the desired Fourier series in $\cos$ and $\sin$

Comment: And $Re((-1)^n \frac{e^{inx}}{-i \pi n}) = \frac{(-1)^n}{-\pi n} \sin(nx)$ while $Re((-i)^{2n} \frac{e^{inx}}{-i \pi n}) = \frac{(-1)^n}{-2\pi n} \sin(2nx)$ and $ Re((-i)^{2n+1} \frac{e^{inx}}{-i \pi n}) = \frac{(-1)^n}{\pi n} \cos((2n+1)x)$

Comment: Wait, where did the $(-i)^{2n}$ and the $(-i)^{2n+1}$ come from?

Comment: The real part of $(-i)^n \frac{e^{inx}}{-i\pi n}$ is a $\sin$ or a $\cos$ depending on $n$ even or odd

Comment: Honestly, I still don't understand. So just because the given $f(x)$ is real, we take the real part of our series of coefficients?